# Need help understanding SQL warning in relation to foreign key checks

Tags: php, sql, foreign-keys, auto-increment

Lately I've been working on my predecessor's unfinished PHP code at my new workplace. It's a CMS flyer generator that uses html2canvas to upload user content & images to templates and then convert them to JPGs that they can print or download.

Packages are the root of templates. Packages have form fields, HTML content layout, CSS, and optionally images.

Templates are the root for bulletins (flyers). Templates all have the same root options (title, color palette, header image, logo, etc). The layout field is generated by whatever packages are uploaded, whichever one the user chooses decides the css and styling of the bulletin.

Bulletins are the product. The user can click 'add bulletin' to get to the form fields page from the options the template provides, and the form fields the package provide. Filling these out injects copy and images into the package layout, and produces an 8x11 page which is then processed by html2canvas to make a JPG.

For some reason, the in-application delete functions just don't work. Beside the point, but also the root of my problem-- Ive been deleting test bulletins, templates, and packages directly from the database via mySQL Workbench II.

Now I'm dealing with a lot of foreign key check warnings, and required options aren't loading at all into new bulletin forms.

```
Warning: Error executing statement: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
(`viastaging`.`brochure_generator_template_header_image`, CONSTRAINT `thi_header_image_id` FOREIGN 
KEY (`header_image_id`) REFERENCES `brochure_generator_template_header_image` (`id`) ON DELETE) in 
/home/content/68/5752668/html/bulletin-generator-demo/framework/core/sql.php on line 101
```

I was hoping someone more experienced could help me understand the structure of this warning. I'm in the database going up and down trying to figure out which tables are parents and children, but it's a staging database and shares space with like, six other sites and isn't well organized. Everything has a prefix at least.. I digress.

I'm afraid to start messing with foreign keys and auto-incrementing columns more than I already have-- at this point I'm wondering if truncating everything and starting over would solve my problem the fastest. I'd appreciate any advice.

Comment: delete child rows from other tables. You are trying to delete from a table where rows in other tables point to. For instance, if a user has an address in the address table, you cant delete the user until his address record has been deleted too. (just as an example)

Comment: Or, cascade the delete (`ON DELETE CASCADE` ), which will automagically remove child records when the parent is deleted.

Comment: @delboy1978uk , I've deleted every relevant child row I could find. I think that's the problem-- Before I was having issues deleting parent rows, so I deleted the children, then the parents and started over. I thought that would be the end of it, but now foreign key constraints are triggering on data being added by the application itself. I think it has something to do with auto-incrementing foreign keys not getting reset.

You can probably tell SQL isn't my forte (not to mention I didn't write any of this). Just wanna understand how the tables in the warning relate. Then fix the database.